# how to get the content of the new tab in the internet explorer in watin?

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, watin

I am using watin for some UI testing. In one of the testing, I need to click a link and open a popup windows in new tab(which I set up in IE9), and get the content of the new tab. However I don't know how  do I ask watin to switch to new tab and get the content.

I've tried to use `SendKeys.SendWait("^{TAB}");`, but doesn't seem to work, the Browser.Html still get the content of the first email.

anyone can shed some lights? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Browser.AttachTo method
See this blog post:
[Link](http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2010/01/browserattachto-and-iattachto.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it a bit more clear this worked for me:

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^{t}");
Thread.Sleep(400);
var newTab = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle(string.Empty)); //this is the new browser instance`